# How 2 android devices get connected on same port of adb server

Tags: android, adb

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqzDj.png) devices [Connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrNjj.png) on same port

Comment: what you want to exactly know ? how it works, how adb does that ?

Answer (score 0):

First goto terminal in android studio and connect your android device with system via USB.

### Here you need to run 2 commands

1. adb tcpip 5555
2. adb connect your_device_ip_address

Make sure your System and your both android devices are connected with same network.